# how to change the way of display the view controller at main storeboard

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, view, controller

This is my screen:

[image: my existing screen]

I want to be showing like this:

[image: what I need]

Comment: Select proper simulator like X series or 11 one!

Comment: I try to find it in window but it isn't there ! can you be more specific ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 11.3.1 you can change it at the bottom of Interface Builder:

[image: Xcode 11.3.1]

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard click on view as: in left bottom side.

[image]